# Want to select all rows that meet multiple conditions and create subset for them

Tags: r

I want to select all the rows that are equal to specific dates. I tried the following:

```
dsCorona <- subset(dsCorona, datum == c("2020-03-07", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-28",
                                       "2020-04-04", "2020-04-11", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-25", 
                                       "2020-04-30"))
```

However, this does not seem to work and I end up with the following error:

In datum == c("2020-03-07", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-21", "2020-03-28",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Youu can use `%in%` instead of `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider use dplyr/tidyverse. If dsCorona is a data.frame (if not, you can cast it), with the dplyr/tidyverse package achive what are you asking would be:

```
dsCorona <- dsCorona %>% filter(datnum %in% c(...vector of those values))
```

I hope it helps!